# Sharepoint 2010 search: How to modify search query before submit (programmatically?)

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm making a custom search box Web Part, similar to the OOTB Web Part from SharePoint
([SearchBoxEx class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.searchboxex.aspx)).

I'm interested in modifying the search query with additional text before it is submitted, based on a custom checkbox added on the Web Part.

Any help on how I can achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

I've used the `AppendToQuery` and `AppQueryTerms` properties, but this will rewrite the text in the search box as well. I'm interested in passing the values "in the background", maybe as an extra parameter. Point is that the query modification should happen without the user seeing it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In the core result webpart there is a property where you can append text to the query and you will not see that in the textbox.

Best,
Bibhu

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the challenge is that I want to append a certain text to the query ONLY when someone checks the checkbox and click on search.

Answer (score 1):

I when I had to customize People Search, I opted to roll my own web part and just called Response.Transfer to the Results.aspx and appended query string parameters to the URL.  This wasn't the most elegant solution, but it was a quick way to modify the query "behind the scenes."

I'm sure you could develop an application page and set it as the Search Box web part's Results page.  Put your custom logic in the page_load and then transfer (or do a form POST) to the actual results.aspx page.

I'm now developing an Extension of SearchBoxEx myself, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to call the base method that submits the query too.  This blog shows how to call the internal CreateAdvanceSearchLink method of the SearchBoxEx class: http://pholpar.wordpress.com/category/search/